# CURL XPATH grab only the first div

Tags: php, html, curl, xpath

I'm trying to grab latest news on a website, using XPath.

The news are in many divs with the same name (and with a class called "p_maj")
Here is an example of the divs :

```html
<div class="p_maj">
  <h1>10 juin 2015</h1>
  <div class="z_b_important">
  <h2>Actualités du projet</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h2>Version Cristal </h2>
  <p>some text</p>
  <h2>Barèmes</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
  <ul>
  <h2>Information</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
  
<div class="p_maj">
  <h1>03 juin 2015</h1>
  <h2>Barèmes</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
  <ul>
  <h2>Outils</h2>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

I would like to have only the first Div (the latest published) on my webpage.

Here is my Curl Script to grab the divs (it works well), but i can't find a way to have only the forst one :

```
        <?php 
$curl = curl_init('http://mywebsite/maj.htm');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$res=$dom->loadHTML($result);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$class = 'p_maj';
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($divs as $div) { 
echo $dom->saveXML($div);
}
?>
```

Anyone knows what kind of instruuction i can use ?

I'm sorry but Php dev is not my speciality...

Thanks to everyone that would answer.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st div with class="p_maj"

```
//div[@class="p_maj"][1]
```

Comment: Do you mean that i should relapce the line 
$divs = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");


with 

$divs = $xpath->query("//div[@class="p_maj"][1]");

 I'm sorry but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Oups... sorry : i have finally understood what you told me. I will post the final code.
Thak you very much !